# Why code error in RStudio (works well on terminal)?: evaluation nested too deeply

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to solve [Euler problem #1](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1) in R:

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

The following code works very well and generate accurate result in Terminal:

```
limit <- 1000
NumSet <- function(n){((1:floor((limit - 1)/n)) * n)}
result <- sum(NumSet(3)) + sum(NumSet(5))- sum(NumSet(15)) 
print(result)
```

When I tried in RStudio, the following error occured:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

What's wrong with this?

```
1 R:        3.0.0
2 RStudio:      0.97.336
3 OS:       ubuntu-12.10,64-bit
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. However, I'm running R (3.0.0.) and RStudio (0.97.309) on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Works ok for me, with RStudio Server, otherwise same systems

Comment: I don't know why you get the error (how do you call the function, can you show us *exactly* what you type?), but you could reduce your function to; `x <- 1:999; sum( x[ x %% 5 == 0 | x %% 3 == 0 ] )` and do it all in one easy step! :-)

Comment: @SimonO101 Thank you. (1) I use `source("euler_1.R")` ; (2) The code works well in Terminal; (3) **Effiency:** your code using list comprehension is fine with small number, when the number goes a little larger, list comprehension is not so effective.

Comment: @Nick when the question is about numbers < 1000 and the code runs in 0.0000675 seconds, for me efficiency is about time it takes to write the code!! :-)

Comment: @Nick I came across a similar issues with respect to the [tag:rstudio] **/** [tag:r] configuration and was wondering if you've managed to decipher what was the source of this problem?